# Code not suppressing submission of the form if the quantity field contains non-numeric data

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've been working on this nonstop and can't get this code to suppress submission of the form if the quantity field contains non-numeric data. Anyone care to take a look at it for me?

https://jsbin.com/kuviqebujo/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" text = "text/css">
        <legend>Customer Information</legend>
        <script language="text/javascript"> 
            function errorMessage(){ 
                var plaQty = document.getElementById("Pla").value; 
                var chiQty = document.getElementById("Chi").value; 
                var spaQty = document.getElementByID("Spa").value; 
                var digits = /[^\s\d]/;
                if (digits.test(plaQty) || digits.test(chiQty)||digits.test(spaQty)){
                    return false;
                    alert("Enter numeric digit");
                } else {
                    alert('Thank you');
                }
            } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method = "post" id="form1" action="/formtest.php" onsubmit="return errorMessage()">
            <br>
            Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
            Address:<br>
            <input type="text" name="Address"><br>
            <br>
            Select your State:
            <br>
            <select id="myState">
                <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            Please select your credit card type:<br>

            <input type="radio" name="credit card"
                value = "American Express"/> American Express

            <input type="radio" name="credit card"
                value = "Visa"/> Visa

            <input type="radio" name="credit card"
                value = "Mastercard"/> Mastercard

            <br><br>
            Enter Credit Card Number:<br>
            <input type="text" name="CCnumber"><br>
            <p>
                Please select the item and quantity below:<br>
            <div>Planer $2</div>
            <input type="text" name="Planer" id="Pla"/>
            <div>Chisel $3</div>
            <input type="text" name="Chisel" id="Chi"/>
            <div>Spanner $10</div>
            <input type="text" name="Spanner" id= "Spa"/>
            <p>
                <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do people format code this way? :/

Comment: getElementByID is misspelled - as seen in the console

Comment: and where is the php for this? Edit: that tag was removed in an edit https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45284616/3

Comment: You are missing a closing `<p>` element on line 51

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton the `</p>` is actually optional.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that doesn't make sense to me lol

Comment: Also change  the 3 numerical fields to `type="number" required` - now you can leave them blank

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - the missing </p> is completely irrelevant to the problem at hand

Comment: @mplungjan I know, that's why I didn't make it an answer ^.^

Comment: Also you need to swap the two statements `return false;alert("Enter numeric digit");`
`

Comment: Type has to be text.

Comment: So fix the typo and swap the statements and you are done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. getElementByID is misspelled - as seen in the console
2. you need to swap the two statements `return false; alert("Enter numeric digit");`

```js
function errorMessage() {
  var plaQty = document.getElementById("Pla").value;
  var chiQty = document.getElementById("Chi").value;
  var spaQty = document.getElementById("Spa").value;
  var digits = /[^\s\d]/;
  if (digits.test(plaQty) || digits.test(chiQty) || digits.test(spaQty)) {
    alert("Enter numeric digit");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert('Thank you');
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="form1" action="/formtest.php" onsubmit="return errorMessage()">
  <br> Name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br> Address:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="Address"><br>
  <br> Select your State:
  <br>
  <select id="myState">
      <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
      <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
      <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
    </select>
  <br>
  <br> Please select your credit card type:<br>
  <input type="radio" name="credit card" value="American Express" /> American Express
  <input type="radio" name="credit card" value="Visa" /> Visa
  <input type="radio" name="credit card" value="Mastercard" /> Mastercard<br>
  <br>Enter Credit Card Number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="CCnumber"><br>
  <p>Please select the item and quantity below:</p>
  <div>Planer $2</div><input type="text" name="Planer" id="Pla" />
  <div>Chisel $3</div><input type="text" name="Chisel" id="Chi" />
  <div>Spanner $10</div><input type="text" name="Spanner" id="Spa" />
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
```

3. However changing the type to number solves it without code

```html
<form method="post" id="form1" action="/formtest.php" >
  <br> Name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br> Address:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="Address"><br>
  <br> Select your State:
  <br>
  <select id="myState">
      <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
      <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
      <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
    </select>
  <br>
  <br> Please select your credit card type:<br>
  <input type="radio" name="credit card" value="American Express" /> American Express
  <input type="radio" name="credit card" value="Visa" /> Visa
  <input type="radio" name="credit card" value="Mastercard" /> Mastercard<br>
  <br>Enter Credit Card Number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="CCnumber"><br>
  <p>Please select the item and quantity below:</p>
  <div>Planer $2</div><input type="number" name="Planer" id="Pla" />
  <div>Chisel $3</div><input type="number"  name="Chisel" id="Chi" />
  <div>Spanner $10</div><input type="number" name="Spanner" id="Spa" />

  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Professor says that the type has to be text.